# Will a 32-bit DirectShow filter work on a 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, dll, com, directshow

Specifically, got a DirectShow filter library in an .AX file, containing the Guliverkli MP4 splitter (version "20050310") downloaded from the MPC/Guliverkli SourceForge pages.

I am experimenting with different DirectShow MPEG-4 splitters using GraphStudioNext (64-bit version), but now I see that it fails to import the filter from file (Graph -> Import Filter from File), giving me error 0x800700C1 when I try to search the AX file for filter CLSIDs.

I suspect this has to do with the fact that the filter is a 32-bit DLL (extension AX, but no matter) while the system and thus its DirectShow subsystem are 64-bit (Windows 7).

Is it the nature of these things? I simply cannot use 32-bit filters here?

<s>Tried also `regsvr32 MP4Splitter.ax` but it got me error 0x80070005, I assume it is much the same problem, but in a different wrapping.</s>

I tried a 64-bit filter for comparison -- the [MPEG-4 splitter from GDCL](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/) -- and it was imported into the above Graph Studio Next without a hitch.

What I want to know specifically is -- can a 32-bit DirectShow filter be installed on 64-bit system, and if it could, am I going about it wrong way?

Comment: `0x80070005` is an "Access denied" error code, so you'll have to execute `regsvr32` with administrative rights.

Comment: @AntonK One and half year later I have come back to upvote your comment and give credit to your [correct] statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to know specifically is -- can a 32-bit DirectShow filter be installed on 64-bit system, and if it could, am I going about it wrong way?

In 64-bit OS, 32-bit application use 32-bit filters (.DLL, .AX etc) and 64-bit applications use 64-bit filters.

More specifically, 32-bit build of GraphStudioNext work with (lists, uses etc) 32-bit filters only. 64-bit of GraphStudioNext only deals with 64-bit filters.

The problems you are experiencing trying to use mentioned filters are specific to these filters or even builds (such as, for example, a missing dependency or the are built with a DEP-unfriendly compiler etc).

Comment: Thank you. Just checked with the 32-bit Graph Studio Next and I indeed could import and use those 32-bit filters that I had. Now, how would I add these to the 64-bit system so that 32-bit applications can use it?

Comment: The same way absolutely. The same 32-bit AX files work equally well in 32-bit OS, and with 32-bit apps in 64-bit OS. On both cases the typical registration of the filters are running them with regsvr32 from administrator's command prompt.

Comment: Haven't checked the 32-bit DLL registration server -- `%WINDIR%\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe` -- but I pretty much now assume that's how I would be registering 32-bit filters on my 64-bit system. If I discover any problems with that, I will always come back here and document it. Until further, I accept your answer regardless. Thanks again.